# What exactly the demons gain from their "contracts", and how do they "level up" from executing contracts?

Tags: high-school-dxd

It seems that it is an routine after-school endeavour for the Gremory to be summoned through their flyers to do devilish stuff like foot massages and claim the dead as their pawns.

Aside from the summon shown in Ep. 1 (when Rias is summoned to claim her Pawn) and the paiting Azazel gives Issei, there are not shown in the anime what rewards the demons gain. It is mentioned towards the end of the second season that Gaspar makes the most out of contracts than any of them.

What do they get from these demonic contracts? And how exactly does fulfilling contracts help a demon rank up?

---

Side note: I have only watched the anime, but answers are encouraged to come from all media.

Comment: IIRC they got money transferred into their account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demon Contract Reward**

Quoted from High School DxD novel Volume One.

> The job goes like this:
>
> First we are summoned, and then we make a contract with them.
>
> After that, we fulfill their wishes.
>
> As a price, we receive an award fitting for the particular wish they made.
>
> It can be money, an object, and even their life.
>
> Well lately, there aren’t any contractors who would use their life to make a wish. Even if there was a person like that, if the price they gave doesn’t match up to the wish they wish for, then the wish won’t be granted. According to Buchou, “People’s values aren’t equal”.

So what demons gets from a contract differs depending on the contract. They can get anything, depending on the agreement.

**Level Up**

As for "level up", I'm not sure what kind of level up you mean, but what has been shown in the story so far is that a demon can get recognized as said by Rias (also from Volume One).

> Since this only increases the number of servants, it doesn’t increase the number of powerful devils. So the devils added a new rule. Chances or opportunities were given to powerful reincarnated devils, in other words devils that were reincarnated from humans. Reincarnated ones are given peerage as well if they are powerful. Because of that there are lots of devils in human’s society. There are also devils like myself who came to human’s society as well. Ise, you may not have noticed but you probably passed devils a couple of times while walking.”

The exact mechanic behind it is not clear, but what was clear is that [Rating Games](https://dxd.fandom.com/wiki/Rating_Games) is one of the methods to "level up" since it is easy to get recognized if you can proof your strength. This is also the method used by Issei.

As for whether doing contract jobs with humans can get a demon recognized and "level up" it is not clear but it probably is possible though might take much longer time.

Answer (score -2):

according to the novel, this demon get their sprite as energy, for others is brave and  on, for our protagonist is oppai :)
Dragon can give the owner power, after the owner have a different view of world and himself.
hope it helps! see novel for more details.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga SE. I'd advise you to add source for the information provided in your answer to improve its quality and credibility. "See Novel" is not a proper source, you can narrow it down from chapter or relate a proper instance.